# Misaligned points in boxplots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I run this ggplot2 code using With this dataset ([download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15gnRA_5arCCisLxDYNPsRLLM1KLhTSP1/view?usp=sharing))...

```
ggplot(data=P4L_melt, aes(variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species), alpha=0.7, lwd=0.5, outlier.shape=NA) + geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0),aes(group=Species, colour=Species), alpha=0.5)
```

I get this plot:
[image]

It seems to be alright. As you can see, we have three groups (red, green, blue), with the respective observations overlapping the boxplots.

However, if we focus on the bottom left corner, where no red group exists, we see that the blue and green points are misaligned (in DC1, DC2, and DC3). 
How can I edit the code to solve this?

Comment: Please add data to question

Comment: I edited my post with a link to download the dataset @PoGibas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's another try, maybe over the top :)

1)
Install latest ggplot2 version:

```
install.packages('tidyverse')
library('tidyverse')
```

2)
Download my modified version of position-dodge2.r and its dependency position-collide.r from my [github](https://github.com/frostell/ggplot2/tree/master/R)

3)
Put these files in your working directory for the project and:

```
source('position-collide.R')
source('position-dodge2.R')
```

4) Now this code should give you what you want!!

```
ggplot(data=P4L_melt, aes(variable, y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species), alpha=0.7) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Species), position=position_dodge2(width=0.75), alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome! Thanks for the codes @frostell, they work nice! And they solve the problem!

Comment: glad if it works! please let me know if there are any bugs/unexpected behaviour with the mod and I'll try and fix it.. also made a PR to the ggplot2 repo, let's see if they merge it :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like geom_boxplot and position_jitterdodge treats NA differently...

Here's an (inelegant) workaround:

1) create a column in your df specifying the x-position of the points:

```
library(ggplot2)
P4L_melt <- read.table('P4L_melt.txt')

P4L_melt$x <- as.numeric(gsub('DC', '', P4L_melt$variable))
P4L_melt$variable <- factor(P4L_melt$variable, levels = paste('DC', unique(P4L_melt$x), sep=''))
P4L_melt$x[P4L_melt$Species=='A'] <- P4L_melt$x[P4L_melt$Species=='A'] - 0.25
P4L_melt$x[P4L_melt$Species=='C'] <- P4L_melt$x[P4L_melt$Species=='C'] + 0.25
P4L_melt$x[P4L_melt$Species=='B'&P4L_melt$variable%in%c('DC1', 'DC2', 'DC3')] <- P4L_melt$x[P4L_melt$Species=='B'&P4L_melt$variable%in%c('DC1', 'DC2', 'DC3')] - 0.2
P4L_melt$x[P4L_melt$Species=='C'&P4L_melt$variable%in%c('DC1', 'DC2', 'DC3')] <- P4L_melt$x[P4L_melt$Species=='C'&P4L_melt$variable%in%c('DC1', 'DC2', 'DC3')] - 0.05
```

2) use that column as the x-position in geom_point

```
ggplot(data=P4L_melt, aes(variable, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species), alpha=0.7, lwd=0.5, outlier.shape=NA) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x, group=Species, colour=Species), alpha=0.5)
```

[image: result..]

Comment: The resulting image is definitively the one I wanted. However, you have to manually edit the code to achieve it. I have more than 30 plots to draw, each one with their own peculiarities. Could it be any more automatic way to plot them?

Comment: how 'peculiar' are they? in what way do they differ? It's sort of difficult to make 100% general solution...