# Why the data misplaced in the boxplot with errorbar in ggplot2

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below,

```
dat<- structure(list(treat = c("A", "CO2","A", "CO2", "A", "CO2", "A", "CO2"), year = c("2013", "2013", "2020", "2020", "2013", "2013", "2020", "2020"), average =c(-27.71561, -28.49894, -28.4279,-29.19103,-27.23562, -34.82991,-27.702, -30.15088), SE =c(0.0498346, 0.0749154, 0.07203569,0.15294481, 0.07090478,0.46597789, 0.1244737,0.2747658), items = c("soil", "soil", "soil","soil","root", "root", "root", "root")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I want to make a boxplot with an errorbar, but I have no idea why the data is not exactly on the same vertical line as 2013 and 2020.

My code is like,

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=year, y=average, group= items))+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')+ 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=items))+
  facet_grid(.~treat)
```

Comment: I've never seen a boxplot with an errorbar. Do you want them side by side? Why might one do this?

Comment: Maybe try faceting by the year

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is being caused by grouping.  I've done the following and got everything to align (note that I've converted the character variables into factors first):

```
ggplot(dat) +
 aes(x = year, y = average, fill = treat) +
 geom_boxplot() +
 scale_fill_hue(direction = 1) +
 facet_wrap(vars(treat))
```

[image]

However, there is also a potential solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240194/misaligned-points-in-boxplots-using-ggplot2):

Comment: So in the above, I've gotten rid of the grouping in the aesthetic call and it aligns.  Anytime there is a grouping included, it seems to throw it out of alignment.

Comment: Yeah, but the above still didn't involve the third variable 'items', which is also the reason I use the group function there.

Comment: Potential solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240194/misaligned-points-in-boxplots-using-ggplot2

Comment: Given that I've now included the link to the solution, do you want to accept my answer?